# Python (django) call two management commands at the same time

Tags: python, django, command, python-unittest, django-unittest

[image]I'm writing unit tests for my management commands. I would like to run my two management commands meanwhile by using call_command() function. How can I do that? I need to run them at the same time because they do work together, one creates data and the other uses that data.

Comment: Could you show us the source of these management commands?

Comment: It's long but I can describe. One of them is actually checks which status room has at that moment inside the while loop and creates datas for that status . Other also work inside while loop and checks datas and change room status. So briefly there are while loops. If you stil need source code, I can share.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: It sounds like maybe neither of your management commands should be a management command. Anyway, we don't need the full source; a [mcve] will do.

Comment: I will pay attention next times thanks for advices, management commands have to be stay as now for temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I certainly don't think this is the right approach, the correct way two run two things "simultaneously" in Python is by using [threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

The following code will launch two threads, each running their own management command.

```
from threading import Thread

def function1():
    call_command('fake')

def function2():
    call_command('engine')

thread1 = Thread(target=function1)
thread2 = Thread(target=function2)

thread1.start() # returns immediately
thread2.start() # returns immediately

import time
time.sleep(3600) # now we wait...
```

A better approach would be to try to create a single management command that does what you need, so threads aren't needed. You will find that using threads, especially as a beginner, will make things needlessly complicated.

Comment: thank you very much, that's whats I want. Actually one of the command is temporary, so we will change it in future but thanks for your advice.